# ng-model returns name of value in place of real value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I have html page using angular.

I have a table with ng-repeat on array:

```
<tr ng-repeat="oblig in Obligations">
```

`oblig` object contains property of `chargeOptionId` connected to another array `ChargeOptions`.

Inside the table there is a `select` element that I want to show details of charge option of `oblig`.

html code:

```
<select class="form-control full-width" ng-model="oblig.ChargeOptionId">
        <option ng-selected="ch.Id == oblig.ChargeOptionId" value="ch.Id" ng-repeat="ch in ChargeOptions">{{ch.Account}}</option>
</select>
```

the `select` element display the charge option details as I want, but when I try saving `oblig`, `oblig.ChargeOptionId="ch.Id"` string in place of value of `ch.Id`.

I tried:

1) using `ng-value`, but the select did not display the data correctly.

2) `ng-options`, but still data was not displayed correctly.

how can I fix that problem?

Comment: Can you post your `oblig` JSON?

Comment: Provide full code. This is not clear.

Comment: You should have a look at NgOption attribute https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
value="ch.Id"
```

to

```
value="{{ch.Id}}"
```

or

```
ng-value="ch.Id"
```

The attribute "value" is not an angular directive (like ng-model and ng-value are) so it doesn't know you intend "ch.Id" as a variable.

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kizijafoka/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: when I changed it to value="{{ch.Id}}" or ng-value="ch.Id" ng-selected did not work, and no charge option was selected.

Comment: So the issue is the dropdown doesn't get an initial value? I'll add my jsbin to my answer and you can see if it works the way you want or if I'm misunderstanding the issue.

Comment: I found the issue: somehow typeof ch.Id was string when type of ChargeOptionId was int. I changed them to the same type and problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was failing before, but this seems to work: I used `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`.

This seemed to do the trick:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Obligations = [
    { ChargeOptionId: 1 },
    { ChargeOptionId: 2 },
    { ChargeOptionId: 3 },
    { ChargeOptionId: 4 },
    { ChargeOptionId: 5 },
    { ChargeOptionId: 6 },
    { ChargeOptionId: 7 }
  ];
    
  $scope.ChargeOptions = [
    { Id: 1, Account: 'Account 1' },
    { Id: 2, Account: 'Account 2' },
    { Id: 3, Account: 'Account 3' },
    { Id: 4, Account: 'Account 4' },
    { Id: 5, Account: 'Account 5' },
    { Id: 6, Account: 'Account 6' },
    { Id: 7, Account: 'Account 7' }
  ];
  
  $scope.alertSelected = function(idx) {
    alert($scope.Obligations[idx].ChargeOptionId);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="oblig in Obligations">
    <div>
      ChargeOption.Id = {{ChargeOptions[$index].Id}} / 
      Obligation.ChargeOptionId = {{oblig.ChargeOptionId}}
    </div>
    <select class="form-control full-width"
            ng-model="oblig.ChargeOptionId"
            ng-options="ch.Id as ch.Account for ch in ChargeOptions">
    </select>
    <button ng-click="alertSelected($index)">Selected value?</button>
    <br /><br />
  </div>
</div>
```